# Ruby on rails toggling favourite button using jquery and ajax comes with "rendering head :no_content Completed 204 No Content' Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a favourite button where users will be able to use toggle button to 'favourite' a post and 'unfavourite' same depending on what they like. So far if I 'unfavourite' the post it seems to work but whenever i do otherwise the link does not change. I used jquery and ajax.

```rb
class FavouritesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @favourite = current_user.favourites.build(favourite_params)
    if @favourite.save
      @post = @favourite.post
      respond_to :js
    else
      flash[:alert] = "something went wrong..."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @favourite = Favourite.find(params[:id])
    @school = @favourite.post
    if @favourite.destroy
      respond_to :js
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something Went Wrong..."
    end
  end

  private

  def favourite_params
    params.permit :user_id, :post_id
  end
end
```

HERE ARE THE MODELS

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favourites

  def is_favourited user
    Favourite.find_by(user_id: user.id, post_id: id)
  end
end
```

FAVOURITE MODEL

```rb
class Favourite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

CREATED J.S IN THE FAVOURITE VIEW FOLDER I.E: views/favourites/created.js.erb

```
$('#favourite').html('<%= j render "posts/favourite", {is_favourited: 
@is_favourited, post: @post} %>');
console.log("Added to your favourite List");
```

CREATED J.S IN THE FAVOURITE VIEW FOLDER I.E: views/favourites/destroy.js.erb
/destroy.js.erb

```
$('#favourite').html('<%= j render "posts/favourite", {is_favourited: 
@is_favourited, post: @post} %>');
console.log("Added to your favourite List");
```

FAVOURITE PARTIAL FILE IN THE POSTS FOLDER IE VIEWS/POSTS/_favourite.html.erb

ON THE SHOW PAGE OF THE POST I RENDERED THE PARTIAL LIKE THIS

```
<%= render 'favourite' %>
```

HERE IS WHAT I GET ON THE CONSOLE

```
No template found for FavouritesController#create, rendering head 
:no_content Completed 204 No Content in 14084ms (ActiveRecord: 318.1ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `create` method doesn't have a view.
If you don't want to respond something, you can add `head :ok` at the end of the method, to avoid the "204" Message.

You can also use `head :created` if you want to respond with "201 Created"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. However, I created a " views/favourites/created.js.erb" as stated above. I don't know if I have to create another view file instead of the 'js.erb' file I created above.

Comment: @Geni check your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` Maybe you have to add `js` as a valid type.